# Storing Elements From A Text Document Into A Map Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

So I have a text document called stock.txt which contains the following:

```
AAPL; Apple Inc.
IBM; International Business Machines Corp.
KO; The Coca-Cola Company
FB; Facebook Inc.
SBUX; Starbucks Corp.
```

And I want to store each element into a HashMap with the stock code as a key and the name of the company as the item. I originally tried storing all of it in an ArrayList however when I wanted to print out one line, for example:

```
AAPL;Apple Inc.
```

I would do:

```
System.out.println(array.get(0));
```

and it would give me the output:

```
APPL;Apple
```

and printing array.get(1) would give me the "Inc." part.

So my overarching question is how to I make sure that I can store these things properly in a HashMap so that I can get the whole string "Apple Inc." into one part of the Map.
Thanks!

Comment: how from storing in a hashmap , you ended up with array list? how did you try to store hashmap structure in array list structure ? can you show us your code plz?

Comment: @radai did you read the op question? and did you see my comment?

Comment: @KickButtowski - yup on both counts, but instead of deriding the OP for mixing up his data structures i was trying to take this someplace constructive

Comment: @radai I did not try to make fun of anyone. I just try to clarify

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
     InputStream stream=new FileInputStream(new File("path"));
     BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
     String line;
     String tok[];
     Map<String, Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
     while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
         tok=line.split(";");
         map.put(tok[0].trim(), tok[1].trim());
     }
     System.out.println(map);
```

Above code reads a file from a specific path and splits the read line from `;` character and stores it into `map`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you couldn't store the information into an ArrayList.  The missing data has more to do with how you are reading and processing the file than the structure in which you are storing it.  Having said that, using a HashMap will allow you to store the two parts of the line separately while maintaining the link between them.  The ArrayList approach does not preserve that link - it is simply an ordered list.

Here's what I would do, which is similar to Darshan's approach (you will need Java 1.7+):

```
public HashMap<String, String> readStockFile(Path filePath, Charset charset)
{
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

  try (BufferedReader fileReader =
        Files.newBufferedReader(filePath, charset))
  {
    final int STOCK_CODE_GROUP = 1;
    final int STOCK_NAME_GROUP = 2;
    /*
     * Regular expression - everything up to ';' goes in stock code group,
     * everything after in stock name group, ignoring any whitespace after ';'.
     */
    final Pattern STOCK_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^([^;]+);\s*(.+)$");

    String nextLine = null;
    Matcher stockMatcher = null;

    while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
      stockMatcher = STOCK_PATTERN.matcher(nextLine.trim());

      if (stockMatcher.find(0))
        if (!map.containsKey(stockMatcher.group(STOCK_CODE_GROUP)))
          map.put(stockMatcher.group(STOCK_CODE_GROUP),
                  stockMatcher.group(STOCK_NAME_GROUP));
    }
  }
  catch (IOException ioEx)
  {
    ioEx.printStackTrace(System.err);  // Do something useful.
  }

  return map;
}
```

If you wish to retain insertion order into the map, substitute HashMap for a LinkedHashMap.  The regular expression stuff (Pattern and Matcher) belongs to the java.util.regex package, while Path and Charset are in java.nio.file and java.nio.charset respectively.  You'll need to use `Path.getRoot()`, `Path.resolve(String filePath)` and `Charset.forName(String charset)` to set up your arguments properly.

You may also want to consider what to do if you encounter a line that is not properly formatted or if a stock appears in the file twice.  These will form 'else' clauses to the two 'ifs'.